# Get google map coordinates from my site and display in android MapView

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, android-mapview

I have a webiste that tracks my cars and shows the result in google map.
I want to display the position of my car on android google maps. How can I get obtain the coordinates and display in MapView? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use geolocation or goole maps api to get coordinates (i.e lat-long) of any location.